# Magento2: How to disable product image cache url?

Tags: magento2, product-images, cache

I want to disable product cache URL. How to get product image URL directly into the path.

Comment: Can you explain more? Where do you want this?

Comment: I have uploaded all images on S3 bucket...I want to use s3 URL path for all Magento 2 images. @SukumarGorai

Comment: That means you are using cdn? if yes then change the required settings in admin(pub directory).

Comment: Yes, I have used CDN, I have also changed Media URL. But other images are displayed except product images because it is getting cache S3 Url and cache folder not generated in S3 bucket. @SukumarGorai

Comment: Can we set All product images path programmatically? @SukumarGorai

Comment: did u solve this issue? I have the same problem.

Comment: Hi @Diaa I have uploaded all images on S3 bucket and customised all media URL's

Comment: But it is not good solution @Diaa.

Comment: customised! how
https://s3.me-south-1.amazonaws.com/images.myapp.com/catalog/product/cache/021a5445bd4418c7815af89045564cdd/OEM/19257603/19257603__P1.jpg
I dont need this part 
/cache/021a5445bd4418c7815af89045564cdd